# create object of the same class that passed object in php

Tags: php, class, oop, object

I have the fallowing situation

```
class A {
   ... 
   public static function Copy($obj) {
      $newObj = new (class of $obj);
      ...
   }
}

class B extends A {
...
}

class C extends A {
...
}
...
$newB = B::Copy($BObject);
$newC = C::Copy($CObject);
```

Can I create a new object of the parameters class, or I have to override method for every inherited class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be able to simplify it, but [`get_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) is the way to go:

```
$class  = get_class($obj);
$newObj = new $class;
```

I couldn't find a one-liner for PHP 5.x or 7.x, but this appears to work in PHP 8.0:

```
$newObj = new (get_class($obj));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this should work for you:

(Here i use [`get_called_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php) to get the class name which is calling the method)

```
<?php

    class A {

        public static function Copy() {
            $class = get_called_class();
            return $newObj = new $class;      
        }

    }

    class B extends A {

    }

    class C extends A {

    }

    $newB = B::Copy();
    print_r($newB);
    $newC = C::Copy();
    print_r($newC);

?>
```

Output:

```
B Object ( )
C Object ( )
```

Comment: Maybe because of my php version or configurations it runs fatal error :/

Comment: @user3125758 nope, my mistake. forgot to copy the right code